# Can I use my phone's sensor to record movements for DSLR stabilization in post?

Tags: camera, dslr, stabilisation

So I heard about this [SteadXP](http://steadxp.com/) which attaches to your camera to record movements for stabilization in post production.

Is there any app for Android that can do the same thing?

Comment: Would love something like this, anyone know of such an app?

Comment: Microsoft Hyperlapse app for Android might be a good example of it but it only processes its own video.